# How to make my app appear in share board of other apps - example whatsApp

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-intent, text

I am trying to read the text file of chat that exported from WhatsApp to my android app.
When I am trying to export the chat text file to my app, it does not appear in the share board of WhatsApp, although I have added the following to the manifest.xml:

```
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Also, here is the Java Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();


    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
        } else {
            // Handle other intents, such as being started from the home screen
        }
    }
}


void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
    String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    if (sharedText != null) {

        Log.d(TAG, sharedText);
        // Update UI to reflect text being shared
    }
}}
```

I went through many explanations, but I could not figure out what is the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Could you update the question so it also shows the <activity> parent tag of the intent-filter?

Comment: Ok. I update it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the intent-filter under the correct activity in AndroidManifest.xml?

This should work in theory, but some apps might not send the proper intent for your app. It is possible that WhatsApp is using "VIEW" instead of "SEND", so try with this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Can you check if the mimeType of the file you're trying to receive from WhatsApp is really "text/plain"?

Comment: Yes... I am 100% sure